# I need to sort php jquery gallery script alphabetically

Tags: php, readdir, alphabetical

know nothing about php, but I have this script that reads a folder and displays a thumbnail gallery, problem is it dosent display alphabetically. Have searched the net and seen that sort does this but have no idea where to start any help would be much appreciated.

heres the script

```
$sitename = $row_wigsites['id'];     
$directory = 'sites/'.$sitename.'/pans';
$allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
$file_parts=array();
$ext='';
$title='';
$i=0;

$dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("There is an error with your image directory!");

while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) 

{

if($file=='.' || $file == '..') continue;

$file_parts = explode('.',$file);
$ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));

$title = implode('.',$file_parts);
$title = htmlspecialchars($title);


$nomargin='';

if(in_array($ext,$allowed_types))
{

    if(($i+1)%4==0) $nomargin='nomargin';

    echo '
    <div class="pic '.$nomargin.'" style="background:url('.$directory.'/'.$file.') no-repeat 50% 50%;">
    <a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" title="Panoramic Stills taken at '.$title.'°" rel="pan1" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>
    </div>';

    $i++;
}
}

closedir($dir_handle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [glob](http://php.net/glob) instead of opendir, something like:

```
$i=0;
foreach (glob($directory.'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $file){
    if($file=='.' || $file == '..') continue;
    $file_parts = explode('.',$file);
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));
    $title = basename($file);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
    $nomargin='';
    if(($i+1)%4==0) $nomargin='nomargin';
    echo '
    <div class="pic '.$nomargin.'" style="background:url('.$file.') no-repeat 50% 50%;">
    <a href="'.$file.'" title="Panoramic Stills taken at '.$title.'°" rel="pan1" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>
    </div>';
    $i++;
}
```

Glob should return sorted list of files.

EDIT: Thanks to Doug Neiner for a tip ;)

Comment: @Habicht you are on the right track, but instead of `*.*` try this: `glob($directory.'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE)` and you can remove the `if(in_array` test.

Comment: Habicht this works a dream only problem now my thumbnail titles include the directory instead of just the file name

Comment: Ah yes, you see - glob returns full path to the file, including directory. So you need to use basename() to get filename itself.
Updated the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

add the sort line as given below

```
$file_parts = explode('.',$file);
sort($file_parts) or die("sorting failed");
$ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));
```

Comment: That would just sort the file parts (file name, extension, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to put the values from the files into an array, then sort the array before outputting it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

@Habicht The Code works fine, but the proper thumbnails are not working anymore since the thumbnails directory reference is removed :

So I tried like this :

```
$i=0;
foreach (glob($directory.'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $file)
{
  foreach (glob($thumbs_directory.'/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $file2)
  {
     if($file=='.' || $file == '..') continue;
     $file_parts = explode('.',$file);
     $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));
     $title = basename($file);
     $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
     $title = str_replace("_"," ",$title);
     $nomargin='';
     if(($i+1)%4==0) $nomargin='nomargin';
     echo '<div class="pic '.$nomargin.'" style="background:url('.$file2.') no-repeat 50% 50%;">
       <a href="'.$file.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>
     </div>';
     $i++;
  }
}
```

The Thumbnails works fine, but the reference image is always the same for any thumbnail - the first image file in $directory. I'm sure there is some other way to combine these foreach statements to fix all at once.